# Website that analyzes excel data

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am quite familiar with C++ and Java for android and now I am trying to use my skills in web programming. 
I have an idea of building the website that analyzes data from excel file (or  csv) in a following way. Let us assume that a row is consist of four sections: name (string), some description (string), some value (int) and a type (string). The user chooses  value and type. First the website checks every row in the column of values and if the value is right, website check the type column. The type that is choosen may be shorter than a content of a section in a given row so the website not only checks if string in row and the choosen are the same but search if in the whole string in a section is any of word that was chosen by user. If all of this is completed, website shows the results by showing two first sections- the name and description.
It doesn't seem hard but I am stuck having no idea from what to begin. I am not asking for a code of course or even very detailed tutorial step by step (however I will be more than gratfull for seekinh detailed answers) but I would like to see what particular steps do I have to do to run this website (including all  things to do in html, javascript and other languages if needed), some good tutorials how to do these things or links to the other questions that may help.
Thank you for all answers and best regards, CM

Comment: This is a very broad question. Do you want to handle everything on the client side (in JavaScript), or server-side? If the latter, what language and/or framework are you planning to use?

Comment: You need to find a host so you can serve content to your users. If you don't want the website to store information when users refresh just use javascript otherwise use a database and some backend to serve up the database information.

Comment: Well, I think that storing information is not needed. If so, is js code enough? What particular things should I learn in js to write the code analizng csv or excel files in mentioned way?